# Android java firebase, запись в базу данных не работает

Tags: java, android, firebase

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Необходимо по ключу фильма взять пользователей, кому понравился фильм и записать все фильмы, понравившиеся данным пользователя в рекомендации к текущему пользователю

Так выглядит база данных фильмов, в like указаны id пользователей
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так выглядит код, который получает id фильма, затем вытягивает всех пользователей из like и передает их в поиск по базе юзеров, откуда выбираются все id фильмов, которые понравились данным пользователям, эти id записываются в рекомендации к авторизованному пользователю

```
 private void isConnectionMatch(String userId) {
    DatabaseReference Filmdb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Films").child("Detective");
    DatabaseReference currentUserConnectionsDb = Filmdb.child(userId).child("connect").child("like");
    currentUserConnectionsDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    DatabaseReference currentUserConnectionsDb = usersdb.child(d.getKey()).child("connect").child("like");
                    currentUserConnectionsDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.exists()){
                                for (DataSnapshot match : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(Detective.this, "new Connect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    String key = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chat").push().getKey();

                                    usersdb.child(match.getKey()).child("connect").child("recommend").child(clientUId).child("ChatId").setValue(key);
                                    usersdb.child(clientUId).child("connect").child("recommend").child(match.getKey()).child("ChatId").setValue(key);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

Код не работает вот здесь: query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
До этого все корректно отрабатывает
Пробовала так, но так записывает понравившиеся фильмы текущего пользователя

```
DatabaseReference currentUserConnectionsDb = usersdb.child(d.getKey()).child("connect").child("like"); 
currentUserConnectionsDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() 
{ 
@Override 
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, уже все кажется перепробовала

Comment: Что значит не работает? Ошибка какая-то? Приведите её нам

Comment: Ошибок нет, но запись в базу данных не идет

Comment: А логах должно быть что-то

Comment: добавила скриншот вначале

Comment: Самое главное у вас закрыто на фото